# Apache kafka client dependency error in nest js

Tags: apache-kafka, nestjs

I have defined producer and consumer codes in the kafka module and trying to use in the separate module but getting this error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CampaignProducer (?). Please make sure that the argument Client at index [0] is available in the MicroserviceClientModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is MicroserviceClientModule a valid NestJS module?
- If Client is a provider, is it part of the current MicroserviceClientModule?
- If Client is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within MicroserviceClientModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Client */ ]
  })
```

The kafka module code:

```
@Module({
    providers: [KafkaService],
    exports: [KafkaService],
})
export class KafkaModule {}
```

This is the kafka service file code:

```
@Injectable()
export class KafkaService implements OnModuleInit {
    private kafka: Kafka;
    private readonly kafkaConfig: KafkaConfig;
    private campaignProducer: CampaignProducer;
    private campaignConsumer: CampaignConsumer;

    constructor() {
        this.kafkaConfig = {
            clientId: 'your-client-id',
            brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
        };
        this.kafka = new Kafka(this.kafkaConfig);
        this.campaignProducer = new CampaignProducer(this.kafka);
        this.campaignConsumer = new CampaignConsumer(this.kafka);
    }

    async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
        await this.campaignConsumer.consumeCampaignMessages();
    }

    getCampaignConsumer(): CampaignConsumer {
        return this.campaignConsumer;
    }

    getCampaignProducer(): CampaignProducer {
        return this.campaignProducer;
    }
}
```

The module where I am trying to import the CampaignProducer:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        KafkaModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        CampaignProducer,
    ],
})
export class MicroserviceClientModule {}
```

The constructor code for the CampaignProducer class:

```
@Injectable()
export class CampaignProducer {
    private producer: Producer;
    private readonly topic = 'campaign-topic';
    private readonly groupId = 'campaign-group';

    constructor(private readonly kafka: Kafka) {
        this.producer = this.kafka.producer();
    }

    async sendCampaignMessage(message: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.producer.connect();
        await this.producer.send({
            topic: this.topic,
            messages: [{ value: message }],
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the constructor of the `CampaignProducer` class?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have added the `CampaignProducer` code in the question

Comment: Are you meaning to inject `Kafka` or the `KafkaService`?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a name in the client registration in your MicroserviceClientModule? Like this:

```
  @Module({
  imports: [
    MicroserviceClientModule.register([
      {
        name: 'name you Defined',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
```

If yes, it will be necessary to inject this name into the Kafka client within the constructor in CampaignProducer:

```
constructor(@Inject('name you defined in the module') private readonly kafka: Kafka) {
    this.producer = this.kafka.producer();
}
```